# Use column alias from SQL query as column header in Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I have the following VBA to get datas from the database using the SQL statement in this VBA:

```
Sub ConnectDB5()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dateVar As Date

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=bi; UID=username; PWD=password; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

    strSQL = " SELECT " & _
                " cID AS Campaign " & _
                " FROM PDW_DIM_Offers_Logistics_history " & _
                " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ""2020-02-24"" "

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

    Sheet4.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

All this works perfectly.

---

However, now I also want that the alias for the `cID` in the `SQL` is displayed as `column header` in the Excel file. 
The result should look like this:

```
            A               B            C
1        campaign
2         001
3         002
4         003
5          :
6          :
7
```

Therefore, I tried to go with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282620/export-sql-query-results-to-excel-using-vba-with-headers) and entered the code in my VBA:

```
Sub ConnectDB6()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dateVar As Date

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=bi; UID=username; PWD=password; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

    strSQL = " SELECT " & _
                " cID AS Campaign " & _
                " FROM PDW_DIM_Offers_Logistics_history " & _
                " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ""2020-02-24"" "

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

        For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheet4.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
        Next

    Sheet4.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

The VBA is running through. However, the alias is not displayed as column name. 
What do I need to change in my VBA to make it work?

Comment: Where are you defining `mrs`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I edited my question. I do not get the runtime error anymore but the alias is still not used as column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get one ROW more with the fieldname:

```
strSQL = " SELECT 'campaign'  UNION ALL SELECT " & _
            " cID AS Campaign " & _
            " FROM PDW_DIM_Offers_Logistics_history " & _
            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ""2020-02-24"" "
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Do you also have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547858/use-multiple-alias-from-sql-query-as-header-of-columns-in-excel

Comment: Not really, see the comment below his question.