# Use multiple alias from SQL query as header of columns in Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547164/use-column-alias-from-sql-query-as-column-header-in-excel/60547371#60547371) I run the below query to

a) get the campaigns in `Column A` and 
b) include the alias in the `SQL` as `header` for the `Column A`.

```
Sub ConnectDB5()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dateVar As Date

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=bi; UID=username; PWD=password; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

    strSQL = " SELECT 'campaign'  UNION ALL SELECT " & _
            " cID AS Campaign " & _
            " FROM PDW_DIM_Offers_Logistics_history " & _
            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ""2020-02-24"" "

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

    Sheet4.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

This query works perfectly.

---

Now, I added one additional column in the SQL query:

```
Sub ConnectDB5()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dateVar As Date

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=bi; UID=username; PWD=password; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

    strSQL = " SELECT 'campaign'  UNION ALL SELECT " & _
            " cID AS Campaign, " & _
            " SUM(order_quantity) AS Quantity" & _
            " FROM PDW_DIM_Offers_Logistics_history " & _
            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ""2020-02-24"" " & _
            " GROUP BY 1"


    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

    Sheet4.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

With this I get:

> runtime error '-2147217887 (80040e21)'

What do I need to change in my VBA to

a) get the campaigns in `Column A` and the Quantity in `Column B` 
b) include the alias in the `SQL` as `header` for the `Column A` and `Column B`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to fix the heading row:

```
strSQL = " SELECT 'campaign', 'Quantity'  UNION ALL SELECT " & _
```

UNION requires all dataset to have the same number of columns.

Comment: When I run this the Column B does not get inserted. It only inserts Column A with the campaign.

Answer (score 0):

When you use union you must have the same number of columns in your selects.

Try this:

```
strSQL = " SELECT 'campaign', '' AS Quantity  UNION ALL SELECT " & _
        " cID AS Campaign, " & _
        " SUM(order_quantity) AS Quantity" & _
        " FROM PDW_DIM_Offers_Logistics_history " & _
        " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ""2020-02-24"" " & _
        " GROUP BY 1"
```

In your first select the Quantity column will have nothing like result.