# Excel ADODB recordset (SQL TRANSFORM) how to sho fieds name

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I've one sheet with data sheets("db_in"), and I tried to create one table using xqry to show the data instead one pivot Table.
This is the qry:

```
Sub CreateXtable()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strsql As String
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
 cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

strsql = "TRANSFORM Count(Count_RST12) AS Nr " & _
        "SELECT Month(DataEnd12) as Mese, switch(IsNull([TipoTrasportoKpi12]),'Anomalie',len(TipoTrasportoKpi12)> 0, [TipoTrasportoKpi12]) AS Kpi " & _
        "FROM [db_In$] " & _
        "GROUP BY month(DataEnd12), switch(IsNull([TipoTrasportoKpi12]),'Anomalie',len(TipoTrasportoKpi12)> 0, [TipoTrasportoKpi12]) " & _
        "PIVOT Kpi12 ;"

rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnspecified

Sheets("Output").Range("K2").CopyFromRecordset rs

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

And this is the result:
[image]
the 1th square you can see the xqry output, in the 2th I show one pivot table from the same data.

In the xqry missing the fields name (Anomalie,OutOffTime,Target1,Target2) how I can show they?!?!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export sql query results to excel using vba with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282620/export-sql-query-results-to-excel-using-vba-with-headers)

Comment: @JoshEller right, I was completely absorbed to writing the correct syntax of my xqry and I thought that the problem was there. Thanks. Fabrizio